# Proving that a problem is in NP

Tags: np-complete, proof-techniques, decision-problem, np

I have an assignment in which the problem, $D$, is simple but, once found, easy to check. Is it enough to prove that a solution $x$ can be checked in polynomial time to prove that $D \in NP$? (The problem $D$ is a decision problem)

Edit: Changed $P$ to $D$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *two* requirements for a problem to be in **NP** are

1. it must be possible to check a given solution in polynomial time;
2. there must be some polynomial $f$ such that solutions to instances of length $n$ have size at most $f(n)$.

Properly, the "solutions" are referred to as "certificates" since they don't have to be an actual solution to the problem. Normally, the certificate to something like a satisfiability problem would be a satisfying truth assignment, but anything that "proves" the instance is in the langauge is acceptable. In particular, the proof that every language in **NP** can be thought of in these terms uses a description of the accepting computation of a Turing machine as the certificate.

This gives intuition why the certificate has to have polynomial length: the Turing machine was only allowed to run for a polynomial number of steps. Indeed, if you dropped the polynomial length requirement on the certificate, even the halting problem would "be in **NP**". The certificate would be a description of the steps taken by the Turing machine before it halts; you can easily check in polynomial time that a certificate is valid, but the certificate itself might have arbitrary length.

Comment: Thank you! Okay so f(n) will work as a kind of upper bound to the length of the solutions? Is there any systematic way to find such a polynomial function or prove that there is one?

Comment: @NyfikenGul Yes, it will. But there's no systematic way of finding what $f$ is. Mathematical proof is a creative act, not a mechanical process.