# Why proving the solution of a problem is polynomial time is sufficient enough to say that it is a NP prolbem?

Tags: proof-techniques, np, proof-assistants

Why proving that we can verify the solution of a problem is polynomial time is sufficient enough to say that the problem is nondeterministic polynomial time? Please note: this is not a question on how to prove a questions is NP, but instead asking why, we can just do so?  If there is more step we need to do, what are missing here?

I am not sure why proving that we can verify the solution of a problem is polynomial time is sufficient enough to say that the problem in NP because seem to me that we can also verify a solution of a problem is polynomial time while it is actually linear time, can't we?

[Proving that a problem is in NP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70722/proving-that-a-problem-is-in-np) seem requires one additional step? it is really necessary ?

Comment: Hey!  There is no such thing as _an NP problem_.  A problem can be _in_ NP, and a problem can be _hard_ for NP and a problem can be _complete_ for NP.  And it can be neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your doubt is legitimate. I assume that you know the difference between deterministic and non-deterministic (e.g. state machines), but maybe this is actually the root of your doubt.

First of all, note that a linear-time algorithm is a polynomial-time algorithm (by definition).

The class $P$ is a subset of the class $NP$, that is, problems that have a (deterministic) polynomial-time solution are also included in the $NP$ class, the class of problems which have a non-deterministic polynomial-time solution. In other words, if you can solve a problem in polynomial time *deterministically*, you can definitely solve it in polynomial time *non-deterministically*.

Therefore, if you are able to verify (*in polynomial time*) that a solution or algorithm $s$ for problem $t$ runs in polynomial time (that is, if you are able to verify that $t \in P$), then you automatically show that the problem $t$ is also in $NP$ (because $P \subset NP$).

Comment: Yes,  i forgot the basic, why "that a linear-time algorithm is a polynomial-time algorithm (by definition)".