# What does an NP reduction look like?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

From my theory of computation lecture I recall:

> If $A \le_m B$ and $B$ is decidable then $A$ is decidable (uses a computable function as a reduction).

> If $A \le_p B$ and $B$ is in P then $A$ is in P (uses a polynomial function reduction).

I wanted to know if there is an analogous notion of reduction for the class NP.

Comment: The very same definition holds for NP as well. Take a look onlike at the class $NP-complete$, and somewhere there you should find about such reductions.

Comment: @nirshahar if you mean the entry of wikipedia for np-completeness, section "Completeness under different types of reduction" then the different types of reductions yield different types (or at least not known to be equal) types of np-complete classes

Comment: The regular reduction definition still holds though, i.e $f:\Sigma^*\rightarrow \Sigma^*$ is said to be a poly reduction if it can be computed in poly time, and $x\in A\iff f(x)\in B$. I don't see a problem using this definition for languages in the NP class. Since the witness is in poly length, the reduction still works, and a similar property holds

Comment: @nirshahar My question is about the most general reductions one can get. This holds indeed. What is the more general class of $f$ I can use, containing the polynomial reductions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that a problem is in NP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70722/proving-that-a-problem-is-in-np)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your replies to nir shahar's comments above, it seems that you're really looking for a class of reduction functions that gives a necessary and sufficient condition, rather than merely a sufficient one as your question arguably implies.

If so, then the answer is rather boring: for any problem *B* in NP, a problem *A* is in NP if and only if it is nondeterministic-polynomial-time Turing-reducible to *B*, that is, if and only if there exists a Turing reduction from *A* to *B* that runs in polynomial time on a nondeterministic Turing machine, or (equivalently) that can be verified in polynomial time on a deterministic Turing machine.

I've specified *Turing*-reducible because a *many-one* reduction is not always available: if *B* is trivial (always returns "yes" or always returns "no"), and *A* is not, then there is no many-one reduction from *A* to *B*, regardless of whether *A* is in NP. However, if we require *B* to be non-trivial, then a nondeterministic-polynomial-time many-one reduction *does* have to exist. (Of course, there are other kinds of reductions besides Turing reductions and many-one reductions; but those are the most commonly discussed.)

Likewise, a polynomial-time reduction is not always available unless P = NP, because if *B* runs in polynomial time and *A* does not, then there won't be a polynomial-time reduction from *A* to *B*, regardless of whether *A* is in NP. However, if we require *B* to be NP-complete, then a polynomial-time reduction *does* have to exist, simply because that's the definition of NP-completeness.

Comment: A reduction must be computable by a *deterministic* TM in polynomial time. Otherwise, NP-hard would make no sense. I could show that SAT can be reduced to binary search (as a decision problem).

Comment: @idmean: I think you've misunderstood something (or else I am). SAT and binary search are both in NP, and the former cannot be reduced to the latter by a reduction that is "computable by a *deterministic* TM in polynomial time" unless it's true that P = NP.

Comment: After rereading I think I understand your premise, and there's nothing technically wrong. It's just a somewhat surprising and confusing definition.

Comment: @idmean: It's not a definition, it's a (trivial) theorem. My understanding is that this theorem is what the question was asking for. Do you interpret the question differently?

Comment: i didn't read in depth in yet. but your first paragraph seems to interpret my question correctly